# Sending an analog input to the system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, joystick

I'm trying to make a joystick. The idea is that I will get an analog input from a pot by arduino I'll send the value to visual studio via serial port and finally I have to put this value as joystick analog input to the system so I'll be able to use it in the games but I couldn't find the command to do this.

I found a command like `SendKey` and I tried it but the result isn't what I needed. For example if I use the `SendKey.Send("a")` the car in the game acts fully turned to left. I want to use the potentiometer like an analog stick. If I turn the pot half way, the steering wheel will turn half way.

Comment: You might be better off having the arduino emulate a serial joystick itself. Also you are not sending it to Visual Studio, you are sending it to a program you just happened to write in Visual Studio. You could have used notepad to write it, Visual Studio has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Which arduino is it? If its one of the USB ones you can make it act like a HID device. Kind of like this: https://code.google.com/p/unojoy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be definitely a better idea to implement a HID joystick profile instead handling serial data and create a virtual joystick in windows via C#. But if it is very important for you to have a virtual joystick check the [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/) project.

As I mentioned above, I would implement a HID Joystick profile. You can do that in many ways and it is not complicated at all.

For example use a Arduino board that have a native supports of joystick HID profile (such as the [Teensy](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_joystick.html) Boards), use a Arduino which you can modify to use a Joystick library (e.g. USBAPI) (like the Arduino Leonardo boards, instructions see [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-USB-Game-Controller-to-Arduino-LeonardoMicro/)), or use a compatible bluetooth module with HID firmware, such as the [RN42 HID](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938) from Sparkfun. There are several example codes for that application in the web.

Comment: You got the job! Come and start tomorrow! :)